# Where can I find more Element Zero?

Tags: mass-effect-2

While my probes have netted me more palladium than I'll ever be able to use, I have played through the entire game finding almost no Element Zero.

Is there a secret to finding planets which contain Eezo, or is there just not much of it out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the other answer, there are lists you can use to find planets for any particular mineral.

If you don't want to use a list, there are a couple of tips:

- Asteroids generally have Eezo.
- Wave your scanner over the planet, if there's any Eezo there, there'll be a lot, and it'll show up immediately.
- You only need ~50k (I think, forgot) to research every single upgrade which needs it, so don't keep mining afterwards (unless you need to respec a lot).
- Game completion bonuses should give you more than the above amount, so you won't need to mine Eezo at all.

Comment: More specifically, only Garden Worlds and Post-Garden Worlds (as defined by the in-game codex / mass effect wiki) have Eezo. Gas giants, etc. *never* will.

Comment: +1 for "You don't need to mine it." I mined waaaay too much on my first playthrough. Eezo, especially, I had far too much of.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty rare, but there are lists floating out there of planets where you can find it. For example, [here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Element_Zero).

Comment: alternately, if you have the Lair of the Shadow Broker DLC after the main mission of the DLC (not of the main story) you'll be able to have them highlighted on the galaxy map.

Answer (score 1):

There is no secret. Element Zero is just very rare.

Here you find a list of planets that have Element Zero:
http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Element_Zero